# iframe css position fails on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, css-position

This seems to work great on all PC browsers, and on Mac/iPhone Safari, but no iframe appears on **Android Chrome**. It should appear half below the bottom, half above... How can I safely achieve bottom positioning?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="700"><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>
    <iframe src="http://www.ibm.com"
      style="position:fixed; left:0px; width:600px; bottom:-200px; height:400px;">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

(This is actually a simplification of much bigger code that has the same problem. Please help...)

Comment: Now I checked it on both Samsung Galaxy S5 and Nexus 5. The problem is on the Samsung but not on the Nexus...

Comment: Forgot to say: The idea is I **have** access to the iframe attributes (which I can change at will), but no access to the parent page code around the iframe.

Comment: Apparently the screen is re-zooming automatically at some point, which makes "position:fixed" elements disappear. A possible workaround seems to be use of "position:absolute" instead, plus calculate and use "top:" instead of "bottom:" (and similarly "right:" instead of "left:" if rtl)